# Converting TopoDS_Shell to bsplinesurface

Tags: python

I am trying to do some surface analysis using pythonocc. I currently have a shell created, but it seems that this can't be used to analyze a surface. I have example methods that uses a bspline surface however I cannot find a way to convert the shell to a surface.

Has anybody attempted something like this?

Comment: can you share the code you have used, the current output and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the procedure. You have to explore the shape (must be a TopoDS_Shape) for faces and then transform them into a brep surface. The code is below:

```
faces = []
    bsurf = []
    faceExplorer = TopExp_Explorer(shape, TopAbs_FACE)
    while faceExplorer.More():
        faces.append(topods.Face(faceExplorer.Current()))
        bsurf.append(BRep_Tool.Surface(topods.Face(faceExplorer.Current())))
        faceExplorer.Next()
```